# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed, ImportError: No module named 'em'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

After installing some rqt related packages, when running "catkin_make" I get:

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Examining the output I see

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named 'em'
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
```

The error persists although I have ran both `python2.7 -m pip install empy` and `sudo apt-get install python-empy`

Anyone has any advise?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239285/invoking-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed,-importerror:-no-module-named-%27em%27/) by [sadisari](https://answers.ros.org/users/27443/sadisari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello , I have fixed it by running pip install empy.

---

Originally posted by [changhai0551](https://answers.ros.org/users/28533/changhai0551/) with karma: 46 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i fixed it with python -m pip install empy

---

Originally posted by [zhouweiguang@hotmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30190/zhouweiguang@hotmail.com/) with karma: 11 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1